# How to get values of a numeric column with column name as a parameter in a for loop in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with numerous numeric columns that I want to analyze one by one, so I am doing this in a for loop rather than copy/paste the same set of code for each variable.
As an example, one of those columns are titled "weight_dry" with values in the 1400 to 1500 (over 180k values in that range).
My question is, how would I refer to this parameter so that its value is recognized and used. For example, the 1st two lines of code below does not filter the values of "weight_dry" as the code section below does when use the variable name explicitly. I figure there must be an easy way to do this - I just don't know and can't find a good reference

this doesn't work, even though I have confirmed that the code knows that, for the 1st iteration of j,  test_par[j]=weight_dry

```
all_data2 <- all_data2 %>%
filter(test_par[j] > 0)
```

whereas, this works just fine:

```
all_data2 <- all_data2 %>%
filter(weight_dry > 0)
```

I tried to use eval() and maybe didn't use it right but didn't work for me (so far).

Answer (score 1):

We can just use `.data` - recommended way to deal with this kind of issue

```
all_data2 <- all_data2 %>%
            filter(.data[[test_par[j]]] > 0)
```

---

or another option is `across` with `all_of`

```
all_data2 <- all_data2 %>%
           filter(across(all_of(test_par[j]), ~ . > 0))
```

Comment: why would you recommend .data over across(all_of), akrun?

Comment: @GuedesBF `across` is to loop over columns.  As there is only a single column, it is easier to just make use of `.data` pronoun

Comment: yeah, makes sense. Using across(selection helper) for single elements do look weird, yet i still prefer the rlang answer (which i learned from you a couple months ago)

Answer (score 0):

If test_par is a character vector of variable names, we have to convert to symbol before evaluating.

We can use `rlang`, convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`):

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

all_data2 <- all_data2 %>%
           filter(!!sym(test_par[j]) > 0)
```

Comment: perfect, that worked. I have tried sym before but without !!, my mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you feel an answer was helpful, please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers